Leaflet Heatmap doesn't show when printing
I develop an Angular app that use leaflet.js and leaflet.heat. to display data. Everything goes well in the app:

But the heatmap doesnt show when I try to print the page using ngx-print:

It seems that ngx-print load the component to print in another component and while rendering,  leaflet's CSS is not loaded (for few seconds) since the map tiles are scrambled:

Everything fix by itself except the heatmap is not displayed.
And if I cancel print, while returned to the original component, the heatmap does't show, I need to full refresh the page to get the correct behavior.
Here the html used to print the page:
<button
    printTitle="Pixhint Rules"
    printSectionId="print-section" 
    ngxPrint
    [useExistingCss]="true">Print</button>
<div id="print-section">
   <ng-template ruleHost>
</ng-template>
</div>

There is nothing special in rule-print.css, only text formatting.
If I try to force using styles.scss of the app and disable useExistingCss, the map is scrambled but the heatmap is displayed:

What's wrong with my code?
